# TouchJSON Fails on Compile (link error)

Tags: objective-c, touchjson

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>
> "_objc_unretainedPointer", referenced from:
>
> ```
>  -[CJSONScanner scanJSONStringConstant:error:] in CJSONScanner.o
>
>  -[CJSONSerializer serializeNumber:error:] in CJSONSerializer.o
> ```
>
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Hey all. Trying to use TouchJSON to do some JSON-y stuff. I followed the read me for the library to the meter I think, but every time I try to compile I get this error. I don't know much about Xcode (I've only been learning Obj-C recently) so I'm clueless about this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove "Experimental" folder (and files inside, of course).

> README
>
> Be aware that the code in the Experimental subdirectory of Source is
>   just that and may not have been extensively tested and/or have extra
>   dependencies

So it could be a problem about extra dependencies (but always make sure if your project already have linked all dependency libraries/framework)